# Golang socket.io middleware

Tags: go, socket.io

Is there any implementation of middleware for `socket.io` event handlers?

https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io

For example,

```golang
io.OnEvent("/", "myEvent", myMiddleware(func(con socketio.Conn) {
  /* my code */
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with this kind of middleware.

You can always write a function that is "in between" another function and the actual handler, which can be used in the way you suggested:

```
func myMiddleware(next func(socketio.Conn) error) func(socketio.Conn) error {
    return func(conn socketio.Conn) error {
        
        // Do some kind of logic in the middleware...
        fmt.Println("Middleware!")
        
        // Now we call the actual function
        return next(conn)       
    }
}
```

This could then be used like you want, e.g. like this:

```
io.OnEvent("/", "myEvent", myMiddleware(func(con socketio.Conn) error {
    fmt.Println("Handler func!")
    return nil 
}))
```

When `myEvent` is received, this would first run the middleware (which prints "Middleware!"), then run the wrapped function (because of the call to `next` in the middleware).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module https://github.com/fakundo/go-middleware

Event handler:

```golang
io.OnEvent("/", "some-event", requireAuth(func(s socketio.Conn) {
  // some event handler code
}))
```

Middleware:

```golang
var requireAuth = middleware.Create(func(s socketio.Conn, next func()) {
  if authorized(s) {
    next()
  } else {
    s.emit("error", AuthError)
  }
})
```